# The mechanism of changing spin orientation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, quantum-spin

Say we have an electron approaching a beryllium cation. According to my general chemistry knowledge, it shall be inserted onto the 2s orbital that is already occupied by another electron. Thanks the Pauli's principle, the resulting orbital ought to have the electrons with their spins oriented differently. How do the approaching electron 'recognizes' that it has to align its spin this or that way? Or is it even that the spin orientation has already been assigned, so the cation must 'wait' until the appropriate electron passes nearby to catch it? So the question is, is it possible for an electron to switch between two possible orientations (and if yes, how) or they're as intrinsic as the spin itself?

Comment: Think about the related with the spin the electrons magnetic dipole moment. In your question replace "spin" by "magnetic dipole moment" and it will be obvious why two electrons in the same orbital are coupled as they are.

Answer (score 7):

The electron may change its spin orientation by using higher order (in multipole orders, say quadrupole) radiation. Those transitions are generally suppressed but still possible. They make meta stable states.

I would think that the electron can enter a higher orbit like 3S or 2P and then later decay into a state which is favorable in energy.

Comment: does the mechanism you mention (3S/2P occupation, followed with decay into 2S with spin opposite that of the single electron already in that orbital) have a characteristic relaxation time?